# php variable to call specific function

Tags: php, function, variables

How would I call a php function from a variable.

For example:

```
$variable = functionname;
```

so when calling $variable this will return functionname();

I have tried the following:

```
$variablereturn = $variable."(sometext)";
print $variablereturn;
```

and

```
print $variable."(".  print $variabletext. ");";
```

neither seem to work.

Comment: Did you try the obvious? `$variable('sometext');"`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: All you need to do is to read manual. But instead you create another question for SO.

Comment: Not sure why I didnt think of that. $variable('sometext'); works thanks Niet its been a long day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following:

```
$variable = 'function_name';
$variable('your_argument');
```

#### [Documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

Comment: I had no idea this was possible.. Since when?